# How to extract year from text in Excel/Google sheets

Tags: excel, google-sheets, excel-formula, google-sheets-formula

I want to extract the year from the Film Title Column using a formula.
[image]

Answer (score 2):

use:

```
=INDEX(IFNA(REGEXEXTRACT(B2:B11; "\d{4}")))
```

Answer (score 1):

From your given sample data, you can use `REGEXEXTRACT()` function to extract years. Try-

```
=REGEXEXTRACT(B2,"\d+")
```

If your actual data have more numbers in each cell and want to extract years before word `Directed` then could Try-

```
=REGEXEXTRACT(B2, " \d+ (?: Directed)?")
```

For array approach. Can use-

```
=ArrayFormula(REGEXEXTRACT(B2:B10, " \d+ (?: Directed)?"))
```

Comment: That 2nd pattern is not going to work as you think it might. You capture 1+ digits between spaces but with an optional non-capture group. So in a string like `Test 1 test 2 Directed`. You'll still capture both digits and GS will output the 1st one. In other words, your optional group has no added value currently.